# Query to GET x within certain date range in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to get count of users whose deadline are within a certain date range.

Answer (score 1):

With `.annotate(count=Count('id'))` you're annotating each row in your queryset with the count of `id`, which is 1, each row has just one id (it would be 1 for any column you pick).

You could then `aggregate` the `Sum` of `count`, which would work, but it's a bit complex compared to the straightforward solution.

Use [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#count) instead:

```
task_qs = Task.objects.filter(...)
total = task_qs.count()
```